# db2 casting not showing proper decimal places

Tags: db2

In this query against db2:

```
select cast (cast col1 as decimal(20,6)/cast col2 as decimal(20,6) as decimal (7,6)) as result from table1.
```

col1 and col2 are both integers. The problem is that the `result` always comes to 2 decimal places instead of 6 decimals.  When I remove the outer cast, the result contains 12 decimal places.

Comment: "_result always comes to 2 decimal places_" -- how do you determine that? May be it's your client that messes up formatting. You can use the `DESCRIBE` CLP command to view the exact data type of the result. If you are concerned about the number formatting for output, you should probably use the string formatting functions available in your version/platform, such as `VARCHAR_FORMAT()`, instead of data type casting.

Comment: You're also potentially chopping off quite a bit of the _front_ of your data, which might be an even bigger problem.

Comment: Once I fix syntax errors, it works fine for me. Without appropriate parentheses, it's impossible to determine your intent. Can we see the actual statement? And @mustaccio is asking a correct question. We should know how you determined what the result format is.